# code generate outputs for all items in the list in python script

Tags: python

I have

```
fruits = [apple, banana, pineapple, oranges]
sizes = [small, medium, large]
```

My code generates files for fruitproperty for each of the fruit-size combination.
I am trying to do this two ways: 
(1) Code will compile for all fruit-size combinations
(2) Code will compile for only specified fruit and it's three combinations.

I require maindir as compulsory argument while fruit name is optional argument

Following is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = " require maindir path and if required fruit name for single compilation")
parser.add_argument('maindir', help = 'Give maindir path', action = 'store')
parser.add_argument("-p","--fruit",help = "Please give fruit name", type=str, default = "apple, banana, pineapple, oranges")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
fruit =[str(item) for item in args.fruit.split(',')]
sys.argv[1]= os.environ.get(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[1])

def compile()
# Code for creating files for fruitproperty for the given fruit-size combination.
```

Then I call the function as below:

```
if sys.argv[3] == fruit: 
   for size in sizes
       compile()
else: 
   for fruit in fruits
       for size in sizes
           compile()
```

so even if I give optional argument, my code is by default compiling for all fruit-size combinations instead of the given specific fruit-size combinations. 
Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: `help = "Please give fruit name'` - quotes are misbalanced, is this present in your original code?

Comment: yes it is. print args gives namespace(maindir = maindir, fruit = apple) but code compiles for all fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

In your first bit of code, you have a **list** `fruit`, which contains the list of fruit passed via a command-line argument. **If it isn't specified**, you have a default of `"apple, pineapple, banana, orange"`.

Keep in mind: `fruit` is a list.

Now, here:

```
if sys.argv[3] == fruit:
```

You're comparing one of the **raw** arguments (a string) with a list. First of all, why are you accessing sys.argv directly if you're using argparse? Second, why are you comparing a string to a list?

Also, this line:

```
for fruit in fruits
```

This "fruit" is shadowing (if different scope) or overwriting the old `fruit` variable. In this case you presume that the user hasn't supplied this parameter so doing so doesn't matter, but keep in mind that that's confusing—you should really be using more descriptive variables!

```
fruit =[str(item) for item in args.fruit.split(',')]
```

Note that the default is `"apple, pineapple, banana, orange"` - it has spaces. So here `fruit = ["apple", " pineapple", " banana", " orange"]` - those spaces are in there and will break string comparisons (if you were going to do any string comparisons). Suggest fixing this line to:

```
fruit = [str(item).strip() for item in args.fruit.split(',')]
```

`strip()` on a string will get rid of leading and trailing whitespace.

For the last bit of code, I suggest:

```
fruits_names = [str(item) for item in fruits]
for arg_fruit in fruit: # for each fruit passed as an argument
    if arg_fruit in fruits_names: # check if it's a valid fruit first
        for size in sizes: # if it's valid, "compile" for all sizes
            compile()
```

Note that I took out the if statement entirely, because you have a default value for `args.fruit` that lists all the fruit, so there's no situation in which you'd not have an `args.fruit` value to iterate over. If you wanted to rely on "no fruits argument = use the full list", set the fruit argument's default to `None` and check for `if args.fruit is None` instead.

Also, your variables are poorly named and make the above code confusing (someone reading the above might ask: "wait, what's the difference between the `fruit` and `fruits` variable?"). Let me suggest renames:

- fruits → valid_fruits
- sizes → valid_sizes
- fruit → arg_fruit_list

That way, it's clear that some of those lists are the valid values, and the other list is the one passed via command line.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. but it doesn't work, now it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Did you fix the spaces problem by calling strip in your list comprehension, as I mentioned? That seems like the first obvious gotcha. Print the two fruit lists (`fruits` and `fruit` per the original names) and check that the strings in the lists match up - if they don't the `if arg_fruit in fruits` line will fail every time. Also, if you renamed any variables, make sure you didn't make any mistakes there!

Comment: Yes, I am using strip() and print gives following outputs: print args: Namespace(maindir = 'maindir', fruit='apple'), print fruit gives ['apple'], print fruits = ['apple','banana','pineapple','oranges']. I didn't change any variables and kept as it is.

Comment: Everything looks fine there. Can you step through the loop, or just add print statements at every block, and check whether it's entering where it's supposed to? You'd expect `arg_fruit == 'apple'` in the one-and-only iteration of the for loop, and for the program to enter the `if` statement, and then for it to iterate over all three `size` values in the inner for loop. If all of that is correct, check your `compile()` function is correct after the changes (why does it not have arguments, anyway?).

Comment: Thanks a lot. so when I print arg_fruit, when it is supposed to print apple , is it giving weird output as o r a n g e (all in vertical manner) . What could be the problem?

Comment: Also when I do not specify any fruit, it still prints the same.

Comment: @geek_xed That suggests `fruit` is a string `"orange"`, and _not_ a list. The for loop is iterating over each character in "orange", so `print(arg_fruit)` is printing 'o', 'r', 'a', etc. each iteration. Are you assigning the variable `fruit` again (in this case to the value `"orange"`) somewhere that you haven't shown?

Comment: No, I haven't assigned fruit to orange anytime. I am not sure why it is taking only last item of the list. can you post your version of code. I might be missing something. it will be really helpful. thanks.

Comment: Made a small edit to the last block of code, since it looks like `fruits` and `sizes` are objects (at first I thought they were strings, my mistake). For the last item thing, maybe you have a for loop that assigns to the `fruit` variable? This would explain the behaviour observed (and is one reason why good, specific names are important). Finally, here's a simplified version of your code that works for what you're asking here (obviously I don't have your fruit objects etc., so I just used strings): http://paste.pound-python.org/show/kb620LR7tjjzadY6YzWg/

Comment: Thanks a lot. but still it is not working for me. Actually my compile code makes use of fruit and size to create some paths and use it. Thus I require the input to be fruit, if given else it should take one by one from the fruits list. This is what all creates problems for the compilation.

Comment: I apologize for the my earlier comment. Your code indeed works!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Variable 'fruit' is a list, but you compare it with a string:

```
fruit =[str(item) for item in args.fruit.split(',')]
if sys.argv[3] == fruit: # this will always be False
```