# python code does not compile for all configurations

Tags: python

This question is in sync with my current question:
[code generate outputs for all items in the list in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359735/code-generate-outputs-for-all-items-in-the-list-in-python-script)

I have,

```
fruits = [apple, banana, pineapple, oranges]
sizes = [small, medium, large]
```

my code is as below:

```
parser= argparse.ArgumentParser(description=' Require path')
parser.add_argument('maindir', help = 'give maindirectory path', action='store')
parser.add_argument("-f", "--fruit", help ='give specific fruit name', type=str, default = "apple, banana, pineapple, oranges")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--size", help='give size', type=str, default="small, medium, large")
args= parser.parse_args() 

# The above code works fine and prints correct arguments
```

Now I am making use of arguments as below:

```
fruit= [str(item).strip() for item in args.fruit.split(',')]
size= [str(item).strip() for item in args.size.split(',')]
for fruit in fruit:
    for size in size:
       if fruit in fruits:
          if size in sizes:
             compile()
```

So my code should compile in three ways:

```
     python fruit.py # This should compile for all fruit-size combinations
     python fruit.py -f fruit # This should compile for all particular fruit-sizes combination. Like apple with (small, medium, large)
     python fruit.py -f fruit -s size # This should compile for particular fruit-size combination.
```

For last two it works fine, but for just `python fruit.py` it just compiles for first fruit in the list with all sizes and stops.

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Given the context with which they appear `if fruit in fruits:` and `if size in sizes:` are tautological. So I would remove those.

Comment: Also you are overriding variable's value by `for size in size:` so it is probably the reason why your code stops working.

Comment: Please provide a short **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are seeing,. It is not at all obvious how to turn those code fragments into such a program.

Comment: The compile function is very big. I can't post.

Comment: Make a copy of your program and delete everything that isn't relevant to your question, like the `compile` function. You should be able to demonstrate the problem in a 10-20 lines program. Make sure that the resulting program is 1) short, 2) complete, and 3) demonstrates the error. Copy-paste *that* program into your question. For more information on this technique, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://sscce.org/.

Comment: After fixing the obvious typos, [your program](http://ideone.com/lFvkjJ) works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Hi Rob, it doesn't work when we specify fruit, or fruit and size

Comment: `for fruit in fruit:` ?! Close this as "a syntactic error" right away!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overriding the value of `fruit` (which is a list of fruits) with another variable named `fruit` on the first iteration of outer loop.

Since `fruit` will start pointing to your first fruit in your list after first iteration, for loop will exit and won't iterate over the rest of the fruits.

I'd recommend you to change your variable names as follows:

```
fruits = [str(item).strip() for item in args.fruit.split(',')]
sizes = [str(item).strip() for item in args.size.split(',')]

for fruit in fruits:
    for size in sizes:
        compile()
```

Hope this helps.

I tweaked your [code](http://ideone.com/1uDfov) and executed in my shell. Here are the results:

```
~ $ python test.py -f watermelon -s small
watermelon small

~ $ python test.py -f watermelon
watermelon small
watermelon medium
watermelon large

~ $ python test.py
apple small
apple medium
apple large
banana small
banana medium
banana large
pineapple small
pineapple medium
pineapple large
oranges small
oranges medium
oranges large
```

Comment: This is what initially I was doing. it compiles for all combinations instead of given ones

Comment: can you try again with the above code and confirm? It works as expected in my command line.